# Why does my timestamp to date format give large years?

Tags: javascript, sorting, timestamp

I am a beginner in Javascript. I am trying to convert from timestamp to date format from an api but i keep getting incorrect, especially with the years, it's larger than usual.

Example

I used this method to convert to date format:

```
                let date = sales.date * 1000
                let dateobject = new Date(date)
```

And this was one of the timestamps from the api : 1608854400000.

This was the output in ddmmyy format: 15-04-52903

Why I am i getting a very high year value?

Comment: The [`new Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) accepts (among others) a number of *milliseconds*. So do not multiply it by a 1000. That is only necessary if the input is in number of *seconds*.

Comment: as @str said, javascript timestamps are in microseconds, not like php, where timestamps are in seconds ;)

Comment: Thank you. That worked.